# How to fetch sub json from request parameter

Tags: java, jquery, servlets

I just decided to send below json data from client to server. Then i found all my previous request were not of type json. And i am unable to send json. Below is the json i want to send in data of jquery ajax.

```
data:{
   id:"10",
   sampleArr:[
         { id:"hello","sample":"hello"},
         { id:"hello1","sample":"hello1"}
   ]
}
```

and at server i get below parameters

```
id=10
group[0][id]=hello
group[0][sample]=hello
group[1][id]=hello1
group[1][sample]=hello1
```

so i am confused how to fetch all groups

Comment: send it in a normal parameter as JSON.stringify(yourJsObk) then in your servlet use some JSON lib to JSONObject x = new JSONObject(request.getParameter("yourParamName");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BigMike, Thanks i am able to fetch complete json and play  around with it. Was unable to send JSON even setting content type application/json. But Still checking why, but working as temperary fix (Might be that i am not using Rest API)

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that what you are sending is not **valid** JSON.

```
{ "data" : {
     "id" : "10",
     "sampleArr": [
         { "id" : "hello", "sample" : "hello"},
         { "id" : "hello1", "sample" : "hello1"}
     ]
  }
}
```

Notice that *all* attribute names must be quoted, and the top-level JSON object must have curly brackets around it.

If that doesn't help, you need to explain how your servlet is receiving and parsing the JSON.

Comment: Its just that i was lazy i didn't write quotes and bracers in code it does exist... On server End i am not tampering request, just reading the values and i am getting it as sampleArr[0][id]="hello" (debuging on this request.getParameterMap())